# Find $\lim_{x\to 0^+} (\sin x)^{(1/\ln(x))}$,without L' Hospital (homework)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I got this home work assignment to find the limit without L'Hospital's rule. I used $e$ like that: $$\sin x^{1/\ln(x)} = \exp\left(\frac{\ln \sin (x)}{\ln(x)}\right)$$ and now I want to find this limit: $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln\sin(x)}{\ln(x)}$, but I couldn't get it through.

Comment: Please learn to typeset using MathJax.

Comment: @TPace  Thanks for the edit, but you should use $\sin x, \ln x, \dots$

Comment: I am confused, daniel. Why are you rolling back the edit, which fix your formatting?

Comment: Note that the limit must be considered for $x\to 0^+$. You first step is correct then you need some manipulation to get the result.

Comment: @daniel let correct the OP with lim $x\to 0^+$

Comment: @gimusi , true, I am not yet familiar with the MathJax, but i'll get used to it. Nice solution by the way, thanks for that.

Comment: @daniel You need to try to get familiar with it. For the solution try always to use standard limits when it is possible. You are welcome, Bye!

Comment: @JohnMa It's good as it is now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x\to 0^+$

$$\Large{\sin x^{\frac1{\log x}}=e^{\frac{\log \sin x}{\log x}}=e^{\frac{\log \frac{\sin x}{x} +\log x}{\log x}}\to e^1=e}$$

indeed

$${\frac{\log \frac{\sin x}{x} +\log x}{\log x}}={\frac{\frac{\log \frac{\sin x}{x}}{\log x} +1}{1}}\to 1$$

Comment: Nice, I didn't see this way!

Comment: Yes we can just use standard limit in this case, but also your solution is nice.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin(x)^{1/\log(x)}=\exp\left(\log(\sin(x))*\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right)$$
$$=\exp\left(\frac{\log(\sin(x))}{\log(x)}\right)$$
Now we can use that $\sin(x)=x+O(x^2)$:
$$\exp\left(\frac{\log(x+O(x^2))}{\log(x)}\right)\to\exp\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)=e$$

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is with *equivalents*:

$\sin x\sim_0 x$, hence 
$$\ln(\sin x)\sim_0\ln x,\enspace\text{so }\enspace \sim_0\frac{\ln x}{\ln x}=1,$$
whence $\;\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln(\sin x)}{\ln x}}=\mathrm e^1=\mathrm e$.

Comment: Yes indeed that's precisely what is going on, anyway I think that asymptotic equivalence must be handled with great attention since is easy for a beginner to fall in error with it for limits which are governed by terms of order greater than 1.

Comment: The only delicate point here is composing by log on the left: the function to be composed must not approach $1$. This being said, it's quite powerful, as it removes all unrelated details.